# USB-C to HDMI Adapter Suspend Issues

Tags: suspend, hdmi, usb-c

First question here.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on a Dell XPS 13 9350. Linux wakes itself up less than ten seconds after putting it into Suspend. Someone on Reddit had me run the command `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup`

```
RP09      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
PXSX      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:01:00.0
RP05      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.4
PXSX      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:3a:00.0
RP06      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.5
XHC       S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
LID0      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
PBTN      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0C:00
```

XHC was disabled using `echo XHC > /proc/acpi/wakeup`. This made the system stay suspended, but (obviously) no longer allowed me to wake up my computer using my keyboard or mouse. This solution is not feasible for me due to the only power button being on my closed, upside-down, and on a very low shelf laptop. I've since re-enabled XHC.

I've found that the system stays suspended without issue once the USB-C to HDMI adapter is unplugged. I've tried disabling the DDC/CI (Display Data Channel / Command Interface) on my monitor (Dell P2715Q), but it did not fix the issue. I'm not sure what other information to give to you, otherwise I would now. Any thoughts?